# How to upload video from custom HTML in a page using WP-stateless?

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-storage, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api

I have custom HTML form in a wordpress page where I would like to allow user to upload videos.My website is already connected to Google Cloud Storage using the WP Stateless plugin.Is there a way to use WP stateless to upload videos from a custom HTMl directly to my google cloud storage bucket?
Here is the code I am using for the custom HTML form

```
<div class="container">
  <form id="custom-video-form">
     <div>
      <label for="uploaded_video">Upload Video:</label>
      <input type="file" id="uploaded_video" name="uploaded_video" accept="video/*">
    </div>
    <div>
    
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>

<script>
document.getElementById('custom-video-form').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  uploadVideo();
});

function uploadVideo() {
  const file = document.getElementById('uploaded_video').files[0];
  const url = '/wp-json/wp/v2/media';

  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', file);

  fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="' + file.name + '"',
    },
    body: formData
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log("Uploaded",data.source_url);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
}

})
</script>
```